# when I click on submit button my javascript first alert box show in mobile device but works fine in desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Its work fine in desktop. but when using mobile device and after fill all information and then click on submit button. its shows alert box  "Answer Question 1"

Below is the script:-

```
        function validateForm()

        {


            if (document.forms["form1"]["ques1"].value==null || document.forms["form1"]["ques1"].value=="") 

            {

                alert("Answer Question 1");
                return false;

            }

            else if (document.forms["form1"]["ques5"].value==null || document.forms["form1"]["ques5"].value=="") 
            {
                alert("Answer Question 5");
                return false;
            }
            else if (document.forms["form1"]["ques6"].value==null || document.forms["form1"]["ques6"].value=="") 
            {
                alert("Answer Question 6");
                return false;
            }
            else if (document.forms["form1"]["ques7"].value==null || document.forms["form1"]["ques7"].value=="") 
            {
                alert("Answer Question 7");
                return false;
            }
            else if (document.forms["form1"]["ques8"].value==null || document.forms["form1"]["ques8"].value=="") 
            {
                alert("Answer Question 8");
                return false;
            }

            else if (document.forms["form1"]["ques9"].value==null || document.forms["form1"]["ques9"].value=="") 
            {
                alert("Answer Question 9");
                return false;
            }
            else if (document.forms["form1"]["ques10"].value==null || document.forms["form1"]["ques10"].value=="") 
            {
                alert("Answer Question 10");
                return false;
            }

        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you add HTML as well?

Comment: You can see the page by going to the link and see page source, Please help

http://shahedalhasan.byethost4.com/quiz_page/quiz.php

Answer (score 0):

Hi I visited the page you mentioned in comments. But I really did not find any issue  except one .

```
<form id="dnaquiz" method="post" name="form1" method="post" action="answer.php" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
```

I see you have used  jQuery, and it has its own way of form handling on mobiles, so you may need to disable it if you want to have classic form handling.

Or you can try to remove `onSubmit="return validateForm()"` and do something like:-

```
$(document).on('submit', '#dnaquiz', function(){ 

    if (validateForm) {
        return true;
   } else {
    return false;    
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.